# Preprocess suggestions in Drupal 7 without Devel Theme Developer module

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming, drupal-preprocess

Is there any alternative way to get preprocess/process suggestions without using Devel themer (Theme developer) module?

Apparently I can use $conf['theme_debug'] = TRUE; to get template suggestions, and dpm or var_dump to list available vars, but I can't seem to find a way to list preprocess/process function suggestions like devel themer does

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: Just looking for a convenient way to see all options in one place

Answer (score 0):

You can use only devel module, not devel_themer

Once installed go to /devel/elements

It will show you a list of all site themes, you can preprocess/process all this elements

[image]